# Jest Equality Matcher For Strings That Disregards Whitespace

Tags: javascript, string, jestjs, matcher, html-escape-characters

Jest's `toEqual` matcher takes whitespace into account when checking for equality. When formatting the expected value in tests it is impossible to do so in a way that matches a string containing newlines, tabs etc.

Does Jest offer a way to disregard whitespace when matching?

Comment: What does `flatErrorMessage` look like? And what do you test?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @Timo says, the only way of doing this appears to be with a custom matcher. Here is one that compresses all whitespace down to a single space for readability based on Jest's [toEqual](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts) matcher. It will deal with tabs, newlines etc. It will give you pretty output like the included Jest matchers:

```
//matchStringIgnoringWhiteSpace.js

import { replace, map, equals } from 'ramda';
import { matcherHint, printReceived, printExpected } from 'jest-matcher-utils';
import diff from 'jest-diff';

const replaceWhitespace = replace(/\s+/g, ` `);
const compressWhitespace = map(replaceWhitespace);

const name = `toEqualWithCompressedWhitespace`;

export default function (received, expected) {
  const [
    receivedWithCompresssedWhitespace,
    expectedWithCompresssedWhitespace,
  ] = compressWhitespace([received, expected]);
  const pass = equals(
    receivedWithCompresssedWhitespace,
    expectedWithCompresssedWhitespace
  );
  const message = pass
    ? () =>
        `${matcherHint(`.not.${name}`)}\n\n` +
        `Uncompressed expected value:\n` +
        `  ${printExpected(expected)}\n` +
        `Expected value with compressed whitespace to not equal:\n` +
        `  ${printExpected(expectedWithCompresssedWhitespace)}\n` +
        `Uncompressed received value:\n` +
        `  ${printReceived(received)}\n` +
        `Received value with compressed whitespace:\n` +
        `  ${printReceived(receivedWithCompresssedWhitespace)}`
    : () => {
        const diffString = diff(
          expectedWithCompresssedWhitespace,
          receivedWithCompresssedWhitespace,
          {
            expand: this.expand,
          }
        );
        return (
          `${matcherHint(`.${name}`)}\n\n` +
          `Uncompressed expected value:\n` +
          `  ${printExpected(expected)}\n` +
          `Expected value with compressed whitespace to equal:\n` +
          `  ${printExpected(expectedWithCompresssedWhitespace)}\n` +
          `Uncompressed received value:\n` +
          `  ${printReceived(received)}\n` +
          `Received value with compressed whitespace:\n` +
          `  ${printReceived(receivedWithCompresssedWhitespace)}${
            diffString ? `\n\nDifference:\n\n${diffString}` : ``
          }`
        );
      };
  return {
    actual: received,
    expected,
    message,
    name,
    pass,
  };
};
```

To register the custom matcher you need to add it to your setupTests files. First register setupTests in your `jest.config.js` using the `setupFilesAfterEnv` field:

```
 setupFilesAfterEnv: `<rootDir>/path/to/setupTests.js`,
```

And then register the custom matcher on the `expect` object.

```
//setupTests.js

import toMatchStringIgnoringWhitespace from "<rootDir>/path/to/matchStringIgnoringWhiteSpace";

expect.extend({
    toMatchStringIgnoringWhitespace: toMatchStringIgnoringWhitespace
});
```

If you are using TypeScript you will also want to add the typings to the `expect` object [following the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227432/how-to-get-a-jest-custom-matcher-working-in-typescript).

Comment: This was super helpful -- only suggested change: `const replaceWhitespace = (str) => str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()` to account for whitespace at the beginning/end of the strings.

Comment: Fantastic. I've updated your answer with most recent standard practises.

Comment: Using the ramda library is "standard practice"?

Comment: Ramda has been a dependency of this snippet since the initial version.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve this with Jest out of the box.

However, you can [write your own reusable matcher using `expect.extend`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectextendmatchers). Remove all whitespace from both strings, e.g. via `str.replace(/\s/g, '')`, and compare the strings.

Comment: I had to use `.replace(/\s+/g, " ")` to replace all white spaces. Note: the `+` after the `\s`

Answer (score -4):

While this is not a direct answer, you can also do:

```
mockedFunction.mock.calls[0] // To get array of arguments

// or 

mockedFunction.mock.calls[0][0] // to get first argument and so on
```

And then compare with equality.